# ActiveRecord - How fast are Calculate() methods in PostgreSQL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, activerecord

I have a rather noobish question about ActiveRecord in ruby on rails. 
I'm working on an app on a Postgresql database that will need to handle large amounts of data from multiple platforms as quickly as possible. I'm going through the process of trying to optimize for speed.

I have two functions and I'm wondering which one would be faster theoretically.

Example #1

```rb
def spend_branded(date_range)
    total_branded_spend = 0.0
    platform_list.each do |platform|
      platform.where(date: date_range).each do |platform_performance|
        total_branded_spend += platform_performance.spend["branded"].to_f
      end
    end

    total_branded_spend
 end
```

VS.

Example #2

```rb
def spend_branded(date_range)
    total_branded_spend = 0.0
    platform_list.each do |platform|
      total_branded_spend += (platform.where(date: date_range).sum(:branded_spend)).to_f
    end

    total_branded_spend
  end
```

As you can see, in the first example, a selection of records are retrieved via the `.where()` method and then are iterated on with the desired field summed manually. In the second example however, I'm making use of the `.sum()` method to do the summing at the database level.

I'm wondering if anyone knows which method is faster in general. I suspect the second method is faster, but is it faster by many degrees?

Thanks so much for taking the time to read this question.

**EDIT:**

As @lacostenycoder pointed out, I should have clarified what `platform_list` is. It references an array with 1 to 3 ActiveRecord collections containing 1 record per each day in the date_range.
Upon benchmarking with the method provided in his answer, I found the 2nd method to be slightly faster.

```
       user     system      total        real
spend_branded  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.003632)
spend_branded_sum  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.002612)
```

(102 records processed)

Comment: Can you tell us  how `platform_list` is defined?

Comment: @lacostenycoder `platform_list` references an array with 1 to 3 ActiveRecord collections containing 1 record per each day in the `date_range`. Thanks for asking, definitely should have clarified that.

Comment: @JordanLagan thanks for clarification.  I'd suggest to test with a large date range.  The bigger the data set, the bigger the difference will be. Small sets of data may seem like minimum difference. But every millisecond adds up the bigger the data, and especially bigger ruby objects.  Also 30% difference is a BIG difference.  Did you test the refactored versions?

Comment: @lacostenycoder Yes, I tested the optimized versions you suggested (thank you so much, just finished a huge refactor). And I think you're correct and the processing time WILL add up, but unfortunately I've started storing data in json objects within my db which makes it unwieldy/impossible? to sum at the db level. I know it's clunky, but following a more best practice relational structure is kind of impossible at this point since we constantly change what data we store and how we split it out. Just trying to prevent future headaches. Thanks so much for your perspective, it was really helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can benchmark your methods for comparison.  Open a rails console `rails c`, then paste this into your console.

```
def spend_branded(date_range)
  total_branded_spend = 0.0
  platform_list.each do |platform|
    platform.where(date: date_range).each do |platform_performance|
      total_branded_spend += platform_performance.spend["branded"].to_f
    end
  end
  total_branded_spend
 end

def spend_branded_sum(date_range)
  total_branded_spend = 0.0
  platform_list.each do |platform|
    total_branded_spend += (platform.where(date: date_range).sum(:branded_spend)).to_f
  end
  total_branded_spend
end

require 'benchmark'
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report(:spend_branded) { spend_branded(date_range) }
  x.report(:spend_branded_sum) { spend_branded_sum(date_range) }
end
```

Of course we would expect the 2nd way to be faster.  We can probably offer more help if you showed more about the model relations and how `platform_list` is defined.

Also you might want to check out the [PgHero gem](https://github.com/ankane/pghero#pghero) which can be helpful in identifying slow queries and where to add indices to get better performance.  In general when done correctly, doing proper calculations at the database level will be orders of magnitude faster than iteration over large sets of Ruby object.

Also you might try to refactor your first version to this:

```
def spend_branded(date_range)
  platform_list.map do |platform|
    platform.where(date: date_range)
      .pluck(:spend).map{|h| h['branded'].to_f}.sum
   end.sum
 end
```

And 2nd version to

```
def spend_branded_sum(date_range)
  platform_list.map do |platform|
    platform.where(date: date_range).sum(:branded_spend).to_f
  end.sum
end
```

Answer (score 1):

[lacostenycoder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58988064/1608057) is correct to recommend that you benchmark your code.

If the values you are trying to sum are directly available in the database, [Calculations](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-calculate) are very likely going to be faster. I do not know how much faster.

If `platform_list` is a collection of models, something like this might work and might outperform your iteration:

```rb
Platform.
  where(date: date_range).
  where(id: platform_list.map(&:id)).
  sum(:branded_spend)
```

Comment: see OP's comment on question. Looks like `platform_list` is NOT a collection, so  your code idea won't work.